# How can I create a 1920x1080p25 preset in Premiere Pro CS4?

Tags: premiere, cs4, full-hd

I need to edit some source material that comes in 1920x1080p25, with a pixel aspect ratio of 1.

However, I'm missing the presets for this, and the closest I can find is HDV 1080p25, which would be 1440x1080 at a pixel aspect ratio of 1.3333. When I try to customize it, I obviously can't just change the PAR or the frame size.

How do I create a sequence that handles my 1920x1080 content?

Answer (score 3):

I don't use CS4 but in CS5.5 you can do it this way: Open the Composition dialog, open the **Settings** tab, and **choose Custom as preset** (this should be the first entry). Now you can change all parameters. To save you preset, click the button **Change preset** at the lefthand bottom.

Answer (score 1):

If you're missing the presets (which is what it sounds like) I have a solution for it [here](http://azcorporatevideo.com/missing-sequence-presets-in-adobe-premiere-pro-cs6-fixed/).

It involves uninstalling the CS suite, then reinstallling premiere as a standalone OR you can just click on help>update (if that option is available for you). There are a few tools you need to download as well to clean it from your registry after uninstalling. The long answer is on my website, hope it helps!